# Screen sharing multiple monitors over network

Tags: windows, mac, multiple-monitors

I have a Macbook Pro and a Windows laptop. I can attach both of them to an external monitor.

Ideally I would like some sort of network based screen sharing so I can use all three screens with my Mac while the external screen is still attached to Windows box.

This would allow me to take my Mac easily when I go for work and help me get to a dual (or triple) screen setup quickly when I come back. I can spend some money for this as well but I would be interested i open source option as first choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RealVNC has a view only option, perhaps more than one client can connect. I have not tested this.

Comment: Yes, more than one client can connect.

Comment: I guess I have to configure it to a virtual window some how. Would I need to connect both my machine to VNC server? How can I simply extend my regular desktop?